# Python index issue

Tags: python, indexing, increment

Below is the code. Why is it behaving so? What is the alternative?

```
line2 = ["a", "b","c","d","e","f","g","a","c", "d","e","g","h",]

for x in line2:
    print("X value is:", x, " and its index is:", line2.index(x))
```

Output is:

```
X value is: a  and its index is: 0
X value is: b  and its index is: 1
X value is: c  and its index is: 2
X value is: d  and its index is: 3
X value is: e  and its index is: 4
X value is: f  and its index is: 5
X value is: g  and its index is: 6
X value is: a  and its index is: 0
X value is: c  and its index is: 2
X value is: d  and its index is: 3
X value is: e  and its index is: 4
X value is: g  and its index is: 6
X value is: h  and its index is: 12
```

Why is it not incrementing ?. How do I resolve. I need increments of index ? Instead of index do we have something like position of X

Comment: How can it know which `"c"` you are asking about? It is giving you the first one.

Comment: Doesnt X value increment for every iteration, { for x in line2} part?

Comment: `X` is the element of the list. Nothing to increment there.

Answer (score 4):

Using that `index` call is *very* costly in each iteration, when you have it for free if you just use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Furthermore, please be aware about how index works, in that you will always only ever get the first time the value comes up.

```
for index, value in enumerate(line2):
     print("X value is:", value, " and its index is:", index)
```

In terms of *cost* of how your implementation, and this answer works. You can't really compare the functionality of `index`, with the functionality of `enumerate`.

Your first list is going to be `O(n)`, naturally because you are simply iterating through the entirety of your list. However, with *each* call to `index`, that in itself is going to be `O(n)`. That is huge in terms of inefficiency.

The `enumerate` iterates through your list once, providing a tuple result where the first value represents your index, and the second is simply the *next* value in your list, thus giving you just a `O(n)` complexity. Your `print` statement, therefore in the solution I am providing bears no cost, because you are simply just outputting the value you already have without any extra computation required.

Comment: Perhaps also mention that `list.index` finds the first occurrence of the target, and therefore ignores any subsequent occurrences (unless the optional parameter is specified)?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Oh right! silly. Yes I'll add that.

Comment: So based on my understanding, using index is Expensive. Is enumerate less expensive.

Comment: @HyderTom You can't even really compare them. Let me update my question to explain this for you.

Comment: @HyderTom Updated. They two different functions entirely, and again, `index` is also not what you want to use in general because as explained it only gives you the index the first item it finds.

Comment: Thank you about that. @idjaw